# PHP Script to Sort a Large Folder of Files into Date based Sub Folders

Tags: php, linux, file

I have a large list of call recordings from a PBX system and I need to sort them into more manageable folders.

Being a bit of a linux noob, how would I search through a specified folder and based on the date of the file, move it into a folder hierarchy.

Example I have 2013/04/23 as the folder structure.

Then I have files with dates as

20130403-blah283.mp3
20130403-blah284.mp3
20130403-blah285.mp3
20130403-blah286.mp3
20130403-blah287.mp3

etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you a starting point:

1. get files
2. iterate through files
3. create new directory/file_name
4. create directory if !exists
5. copy file
6. delete old file

Model:

```
<?php
$base_path = "/PATH_TO_FILES/";
//$files = glob($base_path."*.mp3");
$files = array('20130403-blah283.mp3','20130403-blah284.mp3','20130403-blah285.mp3','20130403-blah286.mp3','20130403-blah287.mp3'); // for testing

foreach($files as $file){
    $pieces = explode("-",$file);
    $new_filename = $pieces[1];
    $timestamp = $pieces[0];
    $directory = substr($timestamp,0,4)."/".substr($timestamp,4,2)."/".substr($timestamp,6)."/";
    if(!is_dir($base_path.$directory)){
        mkdir($directory,0777);
    }
    copy($base_path.$file,$base_path.$directory.$new_filename);
    //unlink($base_path.$directory.$new_filename); // DELETES OLD FILE ONLY UNCOMMENT WHEN YOUR READY!
}
```